# Best XSLT Editor &| Debugger

Tags: debugging, xslt, editor

Other than Visual Studio, what tool have you found best to create, edit, maintain, and possibly debug your XSLT files?

I work on a fairly big project and we have tons of XSLT files and they have grown quite complex in their implementation.

The language seems so brittle. It would be nice to navigate and identify errors more quickly.

Comment: VS2010 64 bit has an unresolved issue where debugging an XSLT crashes VS... Very painful..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've had good results using [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) for XSLT debugging, XPath building, and general XML stuff.

Comment: I second the oxygen recommendation.  Pros:  Good integration with several XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 implementations (MSXSL, Xalan, Saxon), very customizable, cross platform, intellisense.  Cons:  It freezes up more than my other apps do (I use Windows).

Comment: Another Con: The free version is only a trial

Answer (score 5):

[Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Download.aspx) is pretty good at real-time interpretation of your XPATH queries.

[Cooktop](http://www.xmlcooktop.com/) also lets me run my XPATH queries and shows me the XML and HTML generated by running the XSLT against a given XML.

Also, a colleague tells me that newer versions of [Adobe Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/) allows you to associate an XML file with an XSLT file and run the transformation.

Whenever possible i use [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) for change-tracking.

And for navigation, i most often use [VIM](http://www.vim.org/) (or [VIEmu](http://www.viemu.com/)) and sometimes a custom Visual Studio extension that builds an index of the current document's xsl:template and xsl:variable nodes to provide one-click navigation to the root entries.

Answer (score 2):

In my shop we use, Altova Xml spy.

Comment: Link: http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/

Answer (score 2):

I've actually been doing some of this myself recently, and I find that if you're a .NET developer, Visual Studio actually has pretty fair support built right in for xslt files.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use a tool called Xselerator from Marrowsoft.  You can find trial versions floating around the internet but they seem to have gone out of business so you can't buy it anymore.
It was a great tool.

Comment: I uses to use Xselerator, but then switched to oXygen.

Comment: Link: http://download.cnet.com/MarrowSoft-Xselerator/3000-7241_4-10068192.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Visual Studio's natural abilities here (I think the debugger is particularly strong), there's also a profiler add-in: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/xsltprofiler.

Answer (score 0):

I also use Xselerator. As mentioned, one day it just disappeared from the internet. Luckily I licenced it before then.

Comment: Link: http://download.cnet.com/MarrowSoft-Xselerator/3000-7241_4-10068192.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a [XSLT 3.0 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xslt-xpath) for Visual Studio Code:

> provides comprehensive language support for XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1

*Disclosure: I manage this open source project*