# Looking for free lightweight xslt editor

Tags: windows, xslt, editor

As stated I'm looking for a free lightweight xslt editor with following functionalities:

- Intellisense support
- Simple to use (ie. can copy/paste xml & xsl into it and run the transformation)
- Can be used to preview resulting html
- Runs on Windows

Something like xmlspy used to be like (before it got pricey and full of features noone uses)

Comment: Searching "xslt editor": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424708/what-is-the-best-free-editor-for-xslt-and-mybe-xslfo-and-xml , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209211/best-xslt-editor-debugger , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941315/ide-for-xslt-stylesheets , etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I have been using the [XSelerator](http://sf.net/projects/xselerator) for more than 10 years**. It is more than a good XSLT/XML editor.

Provides a good MSXML3/4 debugger and dynamic intellisense, import/include tree navigation, etc.

Comment: A bit more than I need but still the best one yet.

Comment: What happened to XSelerator?  It seems to be gone.